# Listen for windows events immediately after starting process

Tags: c#, hook

I am attempting to execute the following example code:

```
        bool startApp = CaseExecution.LaunchApplication(App);

        if (startApp == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            oRunCases = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            Thread oWaitForWindow = new System.Threading.Thread(SystemEventsListener.StartListener);
            oWaitForWindow.Start();
            oRunCases.WaitOne();
            if (caseExecuted == true)
            {
                oRunCases.Set();
                caseExecuted = false;
            }
        }
```

With supporting methods:

```
    public static void StartListener()
    {
        uint msg = 0xC000;
        IntPtr hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;

        hHook = SystemEventsListener.SetWinEventHook(SystemEventsListener.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, SystemEventsListener.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, IntPtr.Zero,
                SystemEventsListener.procDelegate, processID, 0, SystemEventsListener.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);

        SendMessage(ApplicationState.p, out hwnd, msg, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    }

    private static WinEventDelegate procDelegate = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);

    static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
    IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        if (idObject != 0 || idChild != 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        AutomationLogic.CheckIfWindowExists();
    }

    private static IntPtr SendMessage(Process p, out IntPtr hwnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        hwnd = p.Handle;
        if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            return SendMessage(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        else
            return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

        try
        {
            killApp(appName);
            p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @directory;
            p.Start();
            processID = Convert.ToUInt32(p.Id);
            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File path is not valid");
            processID = 0;
            return 0;
        }
```

The issue I am running in to is the race condition between StartListener being executed which captures the WinEvents and the process being executed. I have been unable to locate a way to start capturing events during process creation. Am I missing something, or is this not possible?

This is being used in automation software. The initial code executed the application to be tested and then started a loop waiting for the foreground window title to match the expected window title. At that point it would grab the controls and it would continue. A colleague of mine mentioned that it might be better to listen to the message pump and when a new CREATE_OBJECT or FOREGROUND message was sent run the same query instead of having a loop with a 20ms sleep in it.

Comment: `if(startApp == false)` .... really ?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain `startApp` is of type `bool`. I don't understand your point.

Comment: Oh, you where complaining about the `== false` for a bool. Personally I find `if(startApp == false)` easier to read than `if(!startApp)` and often use that pattern myself.

Comment: Also, even if it wasn't strictly for readability; Everybody on this site isn't an expert. Pointing out best practices is definitely advisable, but being condescending while doing so is questionable.

Comment: What do you want to archive with this code? It might help to understand if there's another solution for it.

Comment: Absolutely, this is being used in automation software. The initial code executed the application to be tested and then started a loop waiting for the foreground window title to match the expected window title. At that point it would grab the controls and it would continue. A colleague of mine mentioned that it might be better to listen to the message pump and when a new CREATE_OBJECT or FOREGROUND message was sent run the same query instead of having a loop with a 20ms sleep in it.